# Excel IF(OR) - two OR's formula works but three doesn't?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I can get a two possibility formula to work but not a three. I thought it would just be adding a comma for another term then adding a comma for a value. Please can anyone tell me why its not working?

Working one:

```
=IF(OR(C6="buy", C6="hold"),(F5*(D6+1)),(E5*(D6+1)))
```

Not Working:

```
=IF(OR(C6="buy", C6="hold", c6="sell"),(F5*(D6+1)),(E5*(D6+1)),0)
```

Comment: Remove the ***,0*** from the second formula.

Comment: Please provide sample content

Comment: If you are thinking that `C6="buy"` corresponds to `(F5*(D6+1))` and so forth then that is incorrect interpretation of IF formula.

Comment: @shrivallabha.redij Yes that is what i thought. Is this not how it works?

Comment: @Loadwick I have given one approach below. See if it helps.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent - I really could have sworn i tied it without the 0 and it didn't work but clearly didn't as that does seem to be it. Thanks.

Comment: @Loadwick No.  What the first if is saying is: If C6 is either `buy` or `hold` then return `(F5*(D6+1))` else if C6 is niether of those then `(E5*(D6+1))`

Comment: How do you do it for 3 different outcomes , not just true or false?

Comment: Then you want @shrivallabha.redij answer below.  That will do one of three outputs depending on the value in C6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading your problem description couple of times over I think you need below formula:

`=CHOOSE(MATCH(C6,{"buy","hold","sell"},0),(F5*(D6+1)),(E5*(D6+1)),0)`

Comment: That's perfect, thank you shrivallabha.redij. I didn't know about 'MATCH'. This makes much more sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

In your second formula you have two parts `(E5*(D6+1))` and `0` for the Value is False section, this version will work: `=IF(OR(C6="buy", C6="hold", C6="sell"),(F5*(D6+1)),(E5*(D6+1)))`